# Python class inheritance: super() vs. using the parent class name directly?

Tags: python

Assuming Python 2, are these two equivalent?

```
class Parent(object):
    ...

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Child, self).__init__()
```

and

```
class Parent(object):
    ...

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        Parent.__init__()
```

Comment: yes - but more interestingly, why are you asking? Er... Except it must be `Parent.__init__(self)` for the second example

Comment: `super` shines in the case of cooperative multiple inheritance, in the simple case here it is basically equivalent

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga by "cooperative multiple inheritance," do you mean nested inheritance? If so, would you mind elaborating a bit? Thanks

Comment: @mguijarr I'm mainly confused why the design was like that in py2. I understand `Parent.__init__` was bad, since we are explicitly hardcoding the name of the parent class, but `super(Child, self)` approach also requires hardcoding the child class' name...

Comment: @SibbsGambling I don't know what nested inheritance is. Read the following: https://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=281127 and of course, the classic pycon talk https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EiOglTERPEo